# Using the Facebook API from Mono

Tags: facebook-graph-api, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am developing a mobile application with MonoTouch and Mono for Android, and possibly Win8. I need to access the Facebook API, and I would prefer to do that in C# given the above mentioned platforms.

I know that I can make HTTP requests towards the Facebook API myself, but I am wondering if there are any libraries that wraps these for me and give me an object model to program against. I have done some searching around but have mostly come across libraries that are no longer supported or shut down.

Does anyone have recent experience with my problem and can give recommendations?

Comment: good question, I will need to know this as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to follow a native approach to get as close to a seamless integration as I can get.

For iOS that means https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook which are bindings to the official Objective-C Facebook SDK. I have done login so far and that was very easy. With the access token in place I can make future Facebook API calls from a library like the above or I can create a Mono class library with a service that wraps HTTP calls. This service can then be reused in any C# project (such as Mono for Android).

My plan is to do something similar for Android. I have seen people compile the java library in MonoDevelop as an AndroidResource and then create a wrapper which calls into the Java.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook) should help you get started with the facebook integration using Mono for Android.

Comment: I'm getting this:
Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what limitations (if any) there are with regard to using these libraries on a mobile device, but there are some Facebook SDK's for C#.

Here is one -

- [facebook-csharp-sdk](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk)

Comment: Yeah, that is one of my findings. It is however poorly documented and I don't know how well it fares with Mono...